# error cs0570 nested struct "not supported by the language"

Tags: .net, c++-cli

In C++/CLI:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind:Sequential, CharSet=CharSet::Ansi)]
public ref struct NestedStruct
{
public:
    int x;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind:Sequential, CharSet=CharSet::Ansi)]
public ref struct AStruct
{
public:
    NestedStruct nestedStruct;
};
```

In C#:

```
AStruct s = new AStruct();
s.nestedStruct.x = 7; // ERROR cs0570
```

Are nested structs prohibited in C++/CLI? Should the structure be defined in a separate C# assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   NestedStruct nestedStruct;
```

That's a problem, `NestedStruct` is not a value type.  `ref struct` follows native C++ usage where there is no real distinction between a struct and a class, other than that a struct simply has all of its members *public* by default.  The `ref` keyword is the one that really matters, you declared a reference type and not a value type.  A variable of a reference type should be declared with the hat to make it usable by other .NET languages.  Fix:

```
   NestedStruct^ nestedStruct;
```

If you in fact meant to declare a value type (like struct in C#) then you must write:

```
   public value class NestedStruct
   {
   public:
       int x;
   };
```

Or since you make the member public you can use `value struct` and drop `public:` since that's the default accessibility for a struct.

Fwiw, this "feature" was meant to make native C++ programmers comfortable with C++/CLI syntax.  It didn't.